# Codeblock compiled exe link to a dll without system-path-variable (C++)

Tags: c++, dll, frameworks

I'm creating a small framework which multiple programmers is working on at the same time.

We are all working on windows 7 machines with Code::Blocks, MinGW and C++.

We are using OpenCV in this project.

Is there a way where the dll's used in the project can be copied into the folder with the compiled executable. Or is there a way where that we can tell the executable that the dll is in one of the parent folders without defining a new path in the windows system-path-variable?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Use the `-L` option or just specify the full path to the dll directory like `C:\FullPath\mydll.dll`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Code::Blocks, but Visual Studio has a concept of a post-build event.

After a successful build, Visual Studio will execute instructions (DOS commands) listed in the post-build events section of a project's properties.

I'm sure Code::blocks will have a similar mechanism.  You could use this to copy the DLLs to wherever you need them.

You should also be aware of the [DLL search order on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You could also copy the DLLs to a standard location, and your program will look for them there, if they're not found in the same folder as the executable.

I wouldn't be too afraid of modifying the Path variable, it's less permanent than copying various DLLs all over the place!

Sounds like an interesting project.  Good luck!